# How to limit Django-CMS template_choices based on Page parent

Tags: django-cms

This question could probably be solved with a more broad Q: "How to replace a python 2.7 attribute with a property from outside", but maybe there's a Django-CMS way of accomplishing this, so I ask:

I'm trying to limit the template choices of Django-CMS' (v3.4.x) pages based on their parents, so for this I thought of overriding it's `template_choices` with a function, but I see that in Django-CMS' `Page` model it's loaded on creation, like this:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Page(...):
...
TEMPLATE_DEFAULT = get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')[0][0]
template_choices = [(x, _(y)) for x, y in get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')]
...
```

Modifying `get_cms_settins` is out of the question, but I do need to alter `TEMPLATE_DEFAULT` and `template_choices` so that they have the proper values I wish for. Since I'm still fairly new to Django and Python, my question is *where* and *how* do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was to do something like this on my `models.py`:

```
@property
def template_choices(self):
    from cms.utils import get_cms_setting
    templates = [(x, _(y)) for x, y in get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')]
    if self.parent:
        if self.parent.template == 'parent_a.html':
            templates = [('child_A.html', _('Child A'))]
        elif self.parent.template == 'parent_b.html':
            templates = [('child_b.html', _('Child B'))]
        else:
            templates = [('fullwidth.html', _('Fullwidth'))]
    else:
        templates = [('home_page.html', _('Homepage')), 
                     ('parent_a.html', _('Parent A')), 
                     ('parent_b.html', _('Parent B'))]
    return templates


@property
def template_default(self):
    return self.template_choices[0][0]


Page.template_choices = template_choices
Page.TEMPLATE_DEFAULT = template_default
```

And this *is* setting those fields correctly if I try to inspect any instance of `Page`, however when I try to edit any page and I click on the Page>Templates menu, all templates are up for selection, so it seems the `template_choices` and `TEMPLATE_DEFAULT` attributes are being ignored. Inspecting `pagemodel.py` seems to confirm this, since the `get_template` and `get_template_name` methods use `get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')` instead of those fields. Also in `cms_toolbars.py` for the `# templates menu` section `get_cms_setting('TEMPLATES')` rather than `self.page.template_choices` which seems to be the main culprit. So, this question has turned into a bug ticket: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6520